# Angular validation function for a user creation form

Tags: javascript, validation, angular.js, form

I have to make a user creation wizard, there are 3 steps to achieve the insertion of a new user, so every step I have have a validation function to  enable the next step.

As a first step for the following markup:

```
<div>
    <div class="block block-bordered">
        <div class="block-header bg-gray-lighter">
            <h3 class="block-title">Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row" style="vertical-align:middle;">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label>Organisation *</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table style="width:100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="u-table">
                                        <div class="u-row">
                                            <div class="u-cell">
                                                <ui-select ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.ConfederationOrganization" theme="select2" append-to-body="true" ng-disabled="true">
                                                    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                                                    <ui-select-choices repeat="x in ConfederationList">
                                                        <div style="min-height:15px">{{x.name}}</div>
                                                    </ui-select-choices>
                                                </ui-select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="u-cell">
                                                <ui-select search-enabled="true" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.NAOrganization" ng-change="$parent.NAOrganization_Change()" theme="select2" style="min-width:100px;" append-to-body="true">
                                                    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.ShortName}}</ui-select-match>
                                                    <<ui-select-choices repeat="x in $parent.naOrganizationList | filter: $select.search">
                                                        <div style="min-height:15px">{{x.ShortName}}</div>
                                                    </ui-select-choices>
                                                </ui-select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="u-cell">
                                                <ui-select search-enabled="true" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.ClubOrganization" ng-change="$parent.ClubOrganization_Change()" theme="select2" style="min-width:120px;" append-to-body="true">
                                                    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.ShortName}}</ui-select-match>
                                                    <ui-select-choices repeat="x in $parent.clubList | clubFilter : $parent.CurrentUser.NAOrganization | filter: $select.search">
                                                        <div style="min-height:15px">{{x.ShortName}}</div>
                                                    </ui-select-choices>
                                                </ui-select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><img style="width:50px; height:50px;" ng-src="{{$parent.LogoPath}}" img-fallback alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="surname">Surname *</label>
                        <div class="autosuggestion-container">
                            <input ng-class="$parent.CurrentUserValidationClass.Surname" kendo-auto-complete options="$parent.surnameAutoCompleteOptions" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.Surname" type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder='"user surname"' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="email">Email *</label>
                        <input ng-class="$parent.CurrentUserValidationClass.Email" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.Email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder='user email' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name *</label>
                        <input ng-class="$parent.CurrentUserValidationClass.FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.FirstName" placeholder='user first name' />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="u-table">
                            <div class="u-row">
                                <div class="u-cell">
                                    <label for="gender">Gender *</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="u-row u-gender" ng-class="$parent.CurrentUserValidationClass.Gender">
                                <md-radio-group  ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.GenderValue" class="md-primary">
                                    <div class="u-cell u-gender" style="padding-top:5px;">
                                        <md-radio-button ng-value="1" aria-label="M">M</md-radio-button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="u-cell" style="padding-top:5px;">
                                        <md-radio-button ng-value="2" aria-label="F">F</md-radio-button>
                                    </div>
                                </md-radio-group>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="dob">Date of birth *</label>
                        <div class="js-datetimepicker input-group date"
                             data-show-today-button="true" data-show-clear="true" data-show-close="true"
                             data-side-by-side="false" data-format="dateFormat"
                             datetimepicker ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.DateOfBirth" name="dob">
                            <input ng-class="$parent.CurrentUserValidationClass.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Date of birth" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="nationality">Nationality *</label>
                        <div>
                            <ui-select ng-class="{'user-validation-error' :$parent.CurrentUserValidationClass.Nationality == 1}" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.Nationality" theme="select2" style="min-width:120px;" append-to-body="true">
                                <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.CountryName}}</ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="x in NationalityList">
                                    <div style="min-height:15px">{{x.CountryName}}</div>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block block-bordered">
        <div class="block-header bg-gray-lighter">
            <h3 class="block-title">User's Data</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="username">Username *</label>
                        <input ng-disabled="$parent.CurrentUser.IsUser == 1" ng-class="$parent.CurrentUserValidationClass.UserName" ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.UserName" type="text" class="form-control " name="username" placeholder='' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" ng-show="$parent.ProposedUserNames.length > 0">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Proposed Usernames</label>
                        <md-radio-group ng-model="$parent.CurrentUser.UserName" class="md-primary">
                            <md-radio-button ng-repeat="name in $parent.ProposedUserNames" ng-value="name" aria-label="{{name}}">{{name}}</md-radio-button>
                        </md-radio-group>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The purpose of following function is to  have a boolean result to know if the validation step is completed, otherwise I'll break the wizard and I'll set a specific property to the invalid class name, so that I can highlight the related input:

```
$scope.stepValidationOne = function () {
        var result = true;
        var errorClassName = 'user-validation-error';
        var okClassName = '';
        var scope = this.$parent.$parent.$parent;
        var preCondition = result == true;

        var validateCondition = scope.CurrentUser.Surname.length > 0;
        result = validateCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.Surname = validateCondition ? okClassName : errorClassName;

        validateCondition = scope.CurrentUser.FirstName.length > 0;
        result = validateCondition && preCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.FirstName = validateCondition ? okClassName : errorClassName;

        validateCondition = angular.isDefined(scope.CurrentUser.DateOfBirth) && scope.CurrentUser.DateOfBirth != null;
        result =  validateCondition && preCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.DateOfBirth = validateCondition ? okClassName : errorClassName;

        validateCondition = scope.CurrentUser.Email.length > 0;
        result = validateCondition && preCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.Email = scope.CurrentUser.Email.length > 0 ? okClassName : errorClassName;

        validateCondition = validateEmail(scope.CurrentUser.Email);
        result = validateCondition && preCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.Email = validateEmail(scope.CurrentUser.Email) ? okClassName : errorClassName;

        validateCondition = scope.CurrentUser.UserName.length > 0;
        result = validateCondition && preCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.UserName = validateCondition ? okClassName : errorClassName;

        validateCondition = angular.isDefined(scope.CurrentUser.GenderValue) && scope.CurrentUser.GenderValue > 0;
        result = validateCondition && preCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.Gender = validateCondition ? okClassName : errorClassName;

        validateCondition = angular.isDefined(scope.CurrentUser.Nationality) && scope.CurrentUser.Nationality.CountryID > 0;
        result = validateCondition && preCondition;
        scope.CurrentUserValidationClass.Nationality = validateCondition ? okClassName : 1;

        if (result) {
            var d = $q.defer()
            apiService.GetSelectetExistent(scope.CurrentUser.FirstName, scope.CurrentUser.Surname, scope.CurrentUser.DOB).success(function (response) {
                $scope.SelectExistent = response;
                d.resolve(!$scope.SelectExistent.length > 0);
            });

            return d.promise;
        }
        else {
            return result;

        }
    };
```

this is the CurrentUser structure:

```
$scope.CurrentUser = {
    ConfederationOrganization: $scope.ConfederationList[0],
    NAOrganization: undefined,
    ClubOrganization: undefined,
    Surname: '',
    FirstName: '',
    Gender: undefined,
    DateOfBirth: undefined,
    Email: '',
    Nationality: {},
    UserName: '',
    PersonId: undefined,
    Teams: [],
    Positions: [],
    IsMainContact: false,
};
```

I think it can be better, but I don't how to make more readable and efficient, any suggestion?